# Why debug can not step into/force step into Continuation.yield(ContinuationScope) method

Tags: java-19

question occur in OpenJDK 19 when debugging in `VirtualThread.yieldContinuation()`.
At 370 line, i can not step into or force step into the method `Continuation.yield(VTHREAD_SCOPE)`

```
 ...
 try {
        return Continuation.yield(VTHREAD_SCOPE);  //line 370
    } finally {
        ...
 }
```

How can i enter the method ?

Comment: What do you hope to gain by single-stepping into this method?

Comment: well ,  Virtual Thread also may be pinned on carried Thread . I try to find some memory details when yieldContinuation() return false . I means it will helpful for me to clear how it return false or true.

Comment: If you want to know when threads are being pinned, there are JFR events for that.